# Which convex polytopes do not have stellations?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Some polytopes, like the cube and the tetrahedron, do not have stellations (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stellation.html).

Has anyone characterized all convex polytopes (generally or in small dimension) without stellations?